# How can we check for null for particular fields among many?

Tags: apex, trigger

While inserting records for an Account, if the fields are null then default values should be stored , otherwise the the values should get saved with the values stored in custom settings. The insertion should be done using a trigger. What concepts of apex can I use for achieving this. I am new to salesforce.

Comment: `before insert, before update` check fields in `if blank` set default values; One more thing here we don't code if you have any problem then we can help you to solve it;

Comment: Hi Seshu, welcome to SFSE! Your question appears to be asking for other people to write code for you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. I recommend you go through the Apex Code Module in [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules).

Comment: I asked for the concepts we can use to achieve the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [default field values](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_default_field_values.htm&language=en) feature first?